# Writing Multiple Segments using BeanIO throws error as indeterminate size

Tags: bean-io

Please help as writing multiple Segment throws error
"A segment of indeterminate size may not follow another component of indeterminate size"

Sample XML config is

```
        <field name="noOfShipmentContents" type="Integer" />
        <segment name="shipmentContentsPart2"
            class="com.ShipmentContentsPart2"
            collection="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <field name="shipmentContents" type="String" nillable="true" />
        </segment>

        <field name="noOfSpecialServices" type="Integer" />
        <segment name="specialServicesPart3"
            class="com.SpecialServicePart3"
            collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <field name="chrgServCode" type="String" nillable="true" />
            <field name="chrgAmt" type="String" nillable="true" />
        </segment>
    </record>
```

beanio.jar version 2.0.7 and 2.1.0 Both gives same error
What JDK version?
1.6.0.35

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from developer of beanIO Kevin (Thanks) to use occursRef="[name of field]" on segments whose occurrences depend on a preceding field in the same record.

Trick is configuring

```
<field name="noOfSpecialServices" type="Integer" />
    <segment name="specialServicesPart3" class="com.SpecialServicePart3"
   collection="list" occursRef="noOfSpecialServices">
```

This feature is available in beanIO2.1.x